# Completely uninstalling Ubunutu and other Linux OS and then reinstalling

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, 16.04, uninstall, reinstall

So the tasks I wish to complete are the complete un-installation of Ubuntu 14.04 and other Linux OS so that I can reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 on my now fresh computer. I'm hoping that doing so will remedy a handful of problems that I am having.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do a fresh install of 16.04; make sure to choose the "Use Entire Disk for Ubuntu 16.04" option in the installer (rather than one of the "Install alongside" options), and 16.04 will "take over" the entire disk for its own use, deleting everything that used to be on it. There's no need to un-install anything.